# C++20 compiling modules with Visual Studio: doesn't compile or import ixx files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't attempt to compile my .cxx or .ixx files. Here is my .cxx file:

```
export module greetings;

import std.core;

export std::string get_greeting_text()
{
    return "Hello, World!";
}
```

and here is main:

```
import std.core;
import greetings;

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_greeting_text() << '\n';
}
```

I do have these flags set: `/std:c++latest`, `/experimental:module`. Error messages are

```
C:\...\main.cpp(2,17):error C2230: could not find module 'greetings'
C:\...\main.cpp(6,2): error C3861: 'get_greeting_text': identifier not found
```

...but I don't see any line about trying to compile greetings.cxx, so that's got to be the problem. Changing it to .ixx has no effect. What's the fix?

Comment: Since when are `import` and `export` part of C++?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews since c++ 20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

- Add greeting.ixx to Header Files. (It won't work to add it to Source Files.)
- Right-click properties on greeting.ixx, and

  - Set Item Type to C/C++ Compiler
  - Set Excluded from Build to No.
  - Save
- Build

It seems a little flaky. Rebuild failed unless I did a Clean first.

Comment: Item type: "C/C++ Compiler" is not an header file, that would be "C/C+++ Header".  

What are you trying to tell with your first step?

Comment: An .ixx file isn't a header file, but it does need to be compiled by the C/C++ Compiler. Try it and see.

Comment: This helps me!!! Because I changed .h to .ixx manually... and I waste hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Module declaration `export module greetings;` is not yet working on Visual studio 2019.

You may try to add the following compiler opinions for your greetings.cxx file:

```
/module:export /module:name greetings /module:wrapper greetings.h /module:output greetings.ifc -c greetings.cxx
```

Another solution, rename greetings.cxx to greetings.ixx. The .ixx extension is required for module interface files in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a different file extension with MSVC so you can use intellisense in Visual Studio Code, there is actually a work-around.

With the `cl.exe` command, there is an '/interface' option.  You can do like so:

In My cl.exe CommandFile:

```
/interface /Tp UI/ApplicationHost.cpp
/reference ApplicationHost=Build\Debug\ApplicationHost.ifc
UI/WorldEngine.cpp
/link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
Build/Debug/pch.obj
```

> **/Interface** - Let's the compiler know there is an ifc module/header coming up.
> **/Tp** - Forces the compiler to recognize it as a C++ file, useful if renaming to `.cppm`.
> **/reference** - Tells the compiler where to get the dependency information for the following source code.